# Issue with PHP MySQL and insert into UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with php & mysql, insert to database using utf-8.
first file: 
addsite:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
if(isset($data)) {
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$posts[$key] = filter($value);
}
if(isset($posts['type'])){
if($posts['url'] == "http://" || $posts['url'] == ""){
$error = "Add your page link!";
}else if($posts['title'] == ""){
$error = "Add your page title!";
}else if(!preg_match("/\bhttp\b/i", $posts['url'])){
$error = "URL must contain http://";
}else if(!preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i',       $posts['url'])){
$error = "Please do not use special characters in the url.<";
}else{
    include "plugins/" . $posts['type'] . "/addsite.php";
}
}
?>
<div class="contentbox">
<font size="2">
<li>Pick the type of exchange you are promoting from the dropdown menu.</li>
<li>Set the amount of coins you wish to give per user complete(CPC).</li>
<li>The higher the amount of coins the higher the Links position.</li>
</div>
<div class="contentbox">
<div class="head">Add Site</div>
<div class="contentinside">
    <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
    <div class="error">ERROR: <?php echo $error; ?></div>
    <?php }
    if(isset($success)) { ?>
    <div class="success">SUCCESS: <?php echo $success; ?></div>
    <?php }
    if(isset($warning)) { ?>
    <div class="warning">WARNING: <?php echo $warning; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <form class="contentform" method="post">
        Type<br/>
        <select name="type"><?php $select = hook_filter('add_site_select', ""); echo   $select; ?></select><br/><br/>
        Link<br/>
        <input name="url" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($posts["url"])) { echo $posts["url"]; } ?>"/><br/><br/>
        Title<br/>
        <input name="title" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($posts["title"])) { echo $posts["title"]; } ?>"/><br/><br/>
        Cost Per Click<br/>
        <?php if($data->premium > 0) { ?>
        <select name="cpc"><?php for($x = 2; $x <= $site->premcpc; $x++) { if(isset($posts["cpc"]) && $posts["cpc"] == $x) { echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; } else { echo "<option>$x</option>"; } } ?></select><br/><br/>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <select name="cpc"><?php for($x = 2; $x <= $site->cpc; $x++) { if(isset($posts["cpc"]) && $posts["cpc"] == $x) { echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; } else { echo "<option>$x</option>"; } } ?></select><br/><br/>
        <?php } ?>
        <input style="width:40%;" type="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
 </div>
<?php
 }
else
 {
echo "Please login to view this page!";
 }
 include 'footer.php';
  ?>
```

second file , plugin addsite.php

```
<?php
$num1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `facebook` WHERE `url`='{$posts['url']}'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($num1);
if($num > 0){
$error = "Page already added!";
 }else if(!strstr($posts['url'], 'facebook.com')) {
$error = "Incorrect URL! You must include 'facebook.com'";
}else{
mysql_query($qry);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `facebook` (user, url, title, cpc) VALUES('{$data->id}', '{$posts['url']}', '{$posts['title']}', '{$posts['cpc']}') ");
$success = "Page added successfully!";
}
?>
```

when i write arabic language in the form and submit , 
it went to database with unkown language like :

```
 &Oslash;&pound;&Oslash;&sup3;&Ugrave;
```

database collaction : utf8_general_ci

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');

$host       =   "localhost"; // your mysql server address
$user       =   "z*******"; // your mysql username
$pass       =   "m********"; // your mysql password
$tablename  =   "z*******"; // your mysql table

session_start();
$data = null;
if(!(@mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") && @mysql_select_db("$tablename"))) {
    ?>
    <html>
    MSQL ERROR
    <?
    exit;
}

include_once 'functions.php';
require_once "includes/pluggable.php";
foreach( glob("plugins/*/index.php")  as $plugin) {  
  require_once($plugin);  
}  

hook_action('initialize');

$site = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings"));
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Can you post also the code that connects to database (mysql_connect())?

Answer (score 2):

add this line:

```
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Like this

if(!(@mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") && @mysql_select_db("$tablename"))) {
    ?>
    <html>
    MSQL ERROR
    <?
    exit;
}
else{
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
```

Also:
- Add meta charset to the form page

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

or HTML5

```
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Comment: can you add arabic directly to the database using PHPMYADMIN

Comment: the only thing left is the filter() function, $posts[$key] = filter($value); can you remove it just for a while for testing?

Comment: There is a change ... Output became Ù�Ù�Ù�Ù� Instead of  &Oslash;&pound;&Oslash;&sup3;&Ugrave;

Comment: please try to remove all filters (functions that used to filter $_POST) try also to create a form just for adding arabic input, because I can't find the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: Vote +1 for mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); I also met this issue just now and googled and solved by insert the top line to my code. Thanks.